# Validating mac app store receipt in Server

Tags: xcode4, app-store, osx-lion

I am trying to implement in app purchase in my mac application.
I am able to get the product list. Show to user the product list.
I am able to make purchase with my test account. Now I want to verify the receipt in server instead of the application...
What my doubt is. In my bundle i am getting a receipt file which ..should i send the content of that file or i have to send the transaction data to my server for verification.
And in server side what will be the verification process I need to follow

Comment: I'm also interested in that information. Would be nice if somebody could give an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Send the receipt file to the server. and from server send that receipt to the itunes for verification.